# tailwind row and column layout issue

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the below layout to be drafted with Tailwind.

[image: Layout]

`table` section spans two rows and two columns. I started with `grid grid-rows-5`. But I cannot figure out how to get the `table` section.

Comment: can you provide what you have already try to achieve from that we can know exactly where the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the class `col-span-2` and `row-span-2` to the table element which will allow it to take the needed spaces

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="w-full max-w-md">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-none grid-rows-5 bg-yellow-500">
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <table class="row-span-2 col-span-2 border border-gray-500">
        <tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>John Doe</td></tr>

    </table>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
    <div class="border border-gray-500 flex items-center justify-center">div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Now I am trying to understand the code you have written. Thank you!!!